# Add custom background to AlertDialog Buttons

Tags: java, android, alert, android-alertdialog

Is possible to set a drawable resources into the AlertDialog buttons keeping the process easy?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you are also asking about how to make a custom button as well as a custom alert. Use ImageButton:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html

So you will need to both create a custom Alert class as mentioned above and then use ImageButton in the layout so you can replace the button image with whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot customize AlertDialog buttons. You can use Custom Dialog instead. [Customize AlertDialog Footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7081841/customize-alertdialog-footer/7081924#7081924)

Here are details: http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-display-custom-dialog-your-android-application